# Scala: Multiple Instance Like an Array

Tags: scala

I want **instance's array** just like as follow;

```
var ExampleObj = List(10)(new Obj)
```

Then I want to use this as;

```
var (hoge0, hoge1) = ExampleObj(2)(foo0, foo1, foo2)
```

The `(new Obj)` makes **type mismatch**.

```
[error]  found   : unittest.Obj
[error]  required: Int
```

I do **package unittest** for Obj class.
What I make misunderstand ?
Could you please point out that point and how to solve it ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Nothing in your snippets makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you're trying to create a List with 10 instances of `Obj` class?

It can be done using `fill` method, like that:

```scala
List.fill(10)(new Obj)
```